# Unable to creat new key for watson virtual agent

Tags: watson-virtual-agent

I am trying to create a new key for my virtual agent. When  I submit entry to request new key after entering key name the response is always!

"Failed to create new key; try again later"

Answer (score 0):

In this case the issue was tied to a defect where if the last key in the subscription has been deleted, a new key cannot be created.
One way to address is to request a new subscription using a different email address, or reach out to IBM support for an interim solution.